# How can I make Playwright launch chromium instead of using CDP?

Tags: node.js, playwright

```
let current_context_number = {};
async function getBrowserContext(id) {
    let con = await lock.acquire("browser" + id, async () => {
        if (!(id in current_context_number)) {
            current_context_number[id] = 0;
        }
        current_context_number[id]++;
        if (current_context_number[id] >= 100) {
            logger.info("Closing browser to release memory ------------------");
            await delay(15000);
            if (handles[id]) {
                handles[id].close();
            }
            handles[id] = undefined;
            current_context_number[id] = 0;
        }
        if (handles[id]) {
            return handles[id];
        }
        let others = {};
        if (config("NONE_COMPUTER")) {
            others = {
                proxy: {
                    server: `http://127.0.0.1:${config("proxy_port")}`,
                },
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            };
        }
        let program = path.resolve(`C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe`);
        let portNumber = config("port_number");
        let cprocess = spawn(`"${program}" --user-data-dir="${await getAccountDir(id)}"  --remote-debugging-port=${portNumber} --disable-default-apps --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages https://jsonip.com`, {
            shell: true,
            detached: true,
        });
        cprocess.on("message", (v) => console.log(v));
        cprocess.on("error", (v) => console.log(v));
        cprocess.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Disconnected"));
        await delay(3000);
        let browser = await playwright.chromium.connectOverCDP("http://localhost:" + portNumber, {
            timeout: 10000,
        });
        let context = await browser.contexts()[0];
        handles[id] = context;
        return handles[id];
    });
    return con;
}
```

I would like

```
    let browser = await playwright.chromium.connectOverCDP("http://localhost:" + portNumber, {
        timeout: 10000,
    });
```

to launch chromium directly instead of connectOverCDP as when I connect via CDP the webpage is blocking me and detecting it as a CDP browser.

How can I modify the code above to allow that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `playwright.chromium.launch` and specify the Chromium launch options.